# Cannot use MySQL connector/C++ in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, mysql-connector

After configure my cmakelist file, and try to run my code to connect mysql, the error occurs:

```
====================[ Build | server | Debug ]==================================
D:\SOFTWARE\jetbrainTool\apps\CLion\ch-0\231.9011.31\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build D:\zjcfile\weblearn\OTHER\RFID\testcodefiles\server\cmake-build-debug --target server -j 10
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/server.dir/main.cpp.obj
[2/2] Linking CXX executable server.exe
FAILED: server.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\SOFTWARE\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/server.dir/main.cpp.obj -o server.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libserver.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.0/lib64/vs14 -lmysqlcppconn  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
CMakeFiles/server.dir/main.cpp.obj: In function `check_lib':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:82: undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:83: undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
CMakeFiles/server.dir/main.cpp.obj: In function `get_driver_instance_by_name':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_driver.h:116: undefined reference to `sql::mysql::_get_driver_instance_by_name(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# new

set(MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\\include\\jdbc")  
set(MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_LIBRARY_DIR "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\\lib64\\vs14")  

include_directories(${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR})

link_directories(${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_LIBRARY_DIR})
# new

add_executable(server main.cpp)

# new
target_link_libraries(server mysqlcppconn)
#target_link_libraries(server "${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_LIBRARY_DIR}/mysqlcppconn.lib")

# new
```

and here is my c++ code file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include "cppconn/statement.h"

int main() {
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *connection;
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope I can successfully connect to mysql by using C++.

Comment: `C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\\lib64\\vs14` looks like a msvc library and not a MinGW one. Remember for c++ based libraries most of the time you can not mix compilers.

Comment: Actually,MySQL connector/C++ is downloaded from mysql websites, I don't know whether it is from msvc.So how to solve the problem? Do not use MySQL connector/C++?

Comment: `vs14` means `msvc`

Comment: In the middle of the release notes for mysqlconnector 8.0.22 it says this: ***Connector/C++ now can be compiled using MinGW on Windows.
       Thanks to Eric Beuque for the contribution. Note that
       this enables building on MinGW but does not make MinGW an
       officially supported platform for Connector/C++. (Bug
       #31636723, Bug #100248)***  [https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-connector-c-8-0-22/](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-connector-c-8-0-22/)